# Error link is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my code from the html file in script tag

```
var links;
d3.json("sample.json",function(json){links=json;});

var inputlinks=[];
var nodes = {};

inputlinks.push(links);
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, type:link.type});
link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, type:link.typeKBP});
    });
```

In this code am getting an error

```
    TypeError: links is undefined
    links.forEach(function(link)
```

Comment: Is `d3.json` an async call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `d3.json` is an asynchronous call. This means that the code in the handler function will be run when it returns, not immediately. The code after it *is* run immediately though.

To fix, move the rest of the code inside the handler function:

```
d3.json("sample.json",function(json){
  var links = json;
  var inputlinks=[];
  var nodes = {};

  inputlinks.push(links);
  // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, type:link.type});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, type:link.typeKBP});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the information you provide I can only guess that you should include all your loginc inide the callback:

```
var links;
d3.json("sample.json",function(json){
    links=json;
    var inputlinks=[];
    var nodes = {};

    inputlinks.push(links);
    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, type:link.type});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, type:link.typeKBP});
    });   
});
```